# Install issue with minishift and syndesis on linux

Tags: syndesis

Running on Suse Leap 15.2. I have a fresh install of minishift using kvm which is working fine, however when I try to install syndesis it gets through the initial install OK but then it dies while apparantly trying to do a push to my local registry.

I am using the following install command:
./syndesis minishift --install --nodev --deploy-latest --app-options " --addons jaeger"

The output is below:

```
Switching to project "myproject"
Already on project "myproject" on server "https://192.168.42.23:8443".
Please enter the password for the cluster-admin 'system:admin' or just press 'Enter' for no password?: 
Grant user developer permissions
Logged into "https://192.168.42.23:8443" as "developer" using the token provided.

You have one project on this server: "myproject"

Using project "myproject".
Deploying Syndesis operator
Waiting for syndesis-operator to be scaled to 1
NAME                                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jaeger-operator-5b649f977b-x4k8f       2/2       Running   0          57m
syndesis-db-6dfdfc7d7f-kgwpb           2/2       Running   0          57m
syndesis-jaeger-694b6d6648-9nr8x       2/2       Running   0          54m
syndesis-meta-5646bdd9ff-n2r5v         1/1       Running   0          57m
syndesis-oauthproxy-5cd977c9cf-nz6l8   1/1       Running   0          57m
syndesis-operator-85845bc944-65727     1/1       Running   0          22m
syndesis-prometheus-5f4ff48f5b-dwhpw   1/1       Running   0          57m
syndesis-server-9d4d6b44b-fmhhl        1/1       Running   2          57m
syndesis-ui-6988d76fbd-zc54x           1/1       Running   0          57m
syndesis-operator-85845bc944-65727   1/1       Terminating   0         22m
Switching to project "myproject"
Deploying syndesis app.
Install finished.
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/syndesis/syndesis-meta ... 
latest: Pulling from docker.io/syndesis/syndesis-meta
Digest: sha256:66584808cbc4c8b2a97fe3d5a0074d93dd2ce52a46f191a1cfac54b43008dc58
Status: Image is up to date for docker.io/syndesis/syndesis-meta:latest
docker.io/syndesis/syndesis-meta:latest
The push refers to a repository [172.30.1.1:5000/syndesis/syndesis-meta]
659a2260d7ee: Preparing 
81562bebfad3: Preparing 
eab28b32e2ee: Preparing 
66acf59d5d13: Preparing 
82fbe05a11f3: Preparing 
3445c4376959: Waiting 
3a6b4dd42a76: Waiting 
7ca1db3bb13f: Waiting 
3c95a72bbf25: Waiting 
89169d87dbe2: Waiting 
unauthorized: authentication required
ERROR: Last command exited with 1
```

There are a couple of other stackoverflow pages relating to issues with minishift and docker but I am not sure if they apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was failing because I was using the default project 'myproject' instead of one called 'syndesis', so I created one and used it and now it's pushing fine.